# I have built a basic Router system in PHP, but it is not working with my Apache server (using WAMP)

Tags: php, wamp

I encountered an issue where I opened my server using php -S localhost:2020, and all pages worked fine. However, when I switched to using WampServer, it gave me a 'Page Not Found' error.

Here is the code snippet I used for my server:

```
<?php
require "vendor/autoload.php";
session_start();
define('STORAGE_IMG_PATH' , __DIR__."/uploads/img");
$route = new classes\Router();

$route
        ->Get("/",[classes\Home::class , 'index'])
        ->Get("/about",[classes\About::class , 'index'])
        ->Get("/about/create",[classes\About::class , 'getter']);

echo $route->Run($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] , strtolower($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]));
?>
```

When running with WampServer, I encountered the 'Page Not Found' error as shown in the screenshot below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Vd7t.png)

However, when I switched back to using the PHP server (php -S localhost:2020), the pages worked correctly:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74YyO.png)

I have also provided a link to my WampServer Apache httpd.conf configuration file for reference: [httpd.conf](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1UL6d-TP7ufF-m1KGhEh2neHimyi9pZrij9G1bDIarfk/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm unsure why I am experiencing this issue with WampServer. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apache webserver's "pretty url" require that you have modrewrite module installed, loaded and configured, its distributed and loaded by default, but its not configured, you can do it in your config files such as httpd.conf or .htaccess file (when enabled), usually its done by forwarding any request to nonexistent file to the index.php, `php -S` is only development web server and it mimic this behavior by default.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    # enable the rewrite engine
    RewriteEngine On

    # if request does not lead to the existing file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    # and if request does not lead to the existing folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    # and if URL path match pattern, forward the request to index.php
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    # you may want to exclude some cases
    # like generated javascript or images pulled from db, do so by the pattern
</IfModule>
```

Note that in case of using per-folder config (the .htaccess) you also need the `Options FollowSymLinks`, and what is going to be matched by the RewriteRule pattern does change based on location of this config, more info [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched).